# Which is the best ASP.NET Web Hosting in France?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Can you give me a list of the best ASP.NET Web hosting companies situated in France?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A place to start would probably be [Microsoft's suggested hosting](http://www.microsoft.com/web/hosting/home). Although they might have paid MS to advertise there, but there might be some good offers there.